# Maxwell Wave Equation intuition

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, magnetostatics

It is well known that a change on the electric field, will provoke a change on the magnetic field and vice versa.

If you (with maths or in real life) change a little bit the electric field, then the magnetic field should be affected, affecting the electric field, affecting the magnetic field... making a wave (hence we should find a wave equation as our solution).

---

##### Maxwell's Equations:

$$
\mathbf{\nabla \cdot E} = \frac{\rho}{\varepsilon_0} \\
\mathbf{\nabla \cdot B} = 0 \\
\mathbf{\nabla \times E} = -\frac{\partial \mathbf B}{\partial t} \\
\mathbf{\nabla \times B} = \mu_0\mathbf{J} + \mu_0 \varepsilon_0 \frac{\partial \mathbf E}{\partial t}
$$

---

Setting the charge density, $\rho$, to 0 and the current density, $\mathbf J$, to $\vec{0}$, we have Maxwell's Equations in the Vaccum:
$$
\mathbf{\nabla \cdot E} = 0 \\
\mathbf{\nabla \cdot B} = 0 \\
\mathbf{\nabla \times E} = -\frac{\partial \mathbf B}{\partial t} \\
\mathbf{\nabla \times B} = \mu_0 \varepsilon_0 \frac{\partial \mathbf E}{\partial t}
$$
Taking the curl of the curl of  the $\mathbf E$ field:
$$
\mathbf{\nabla \times \nabla \times E} = -\frac{\partial}{\partial t} (\nabla \times \mathbf B) \\
\nabla(\nabla \cdot \mathbf E) - \nabla^2 \mathbf E = -\mu_0 \varepsilon_0\frac{\partial^2 \mathbf E}{\partial t^2}\\
\nabla^2 \mathbf E = \mu_0 \varepsilon_0\frac{\partial^2 \mathbf E}{\partial t^2}
$$
Same goes for the $\mathbf B$ field:
$$
\nabla^2 \mathbf B = \mu_0 \varepsilon_0\frac{\partial^2 \mathbf B}{\partial t^2}
$$

---

My question is, why taking "the curl of the curl" of both fields gives this solution? Does this "curl of the curl" means what I said before, that a change on the $\mathbf E$ field provokes a change on the $\mathbf B$ field, and so on? If not, what is the mathematical and geometrical meaning of this "curl of the curl"? How would you know that the $\mathbf E$ field is perpendicular to the $\mathbf B$ field in this wave?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The curl of the curl is simply a mathematical operation defined in vector calculus. There is no need to give a physical interpretation to every individual step in a mathematical calculation -- that way lies madness. The physics comes from understanding the inputs and assumptions that go into a calculation, and how to interpret the outputs of the calculation.

Here, the inputs are Maxwells equations. Of course, physically, Maxwell's equations are very important, and tell us how the electric and magnetic fields are related to each other, and how they evolve in time. In order to take a curl of the equations, we have to assume that the fields are sufficiently smooth to be differentiated twice. This is fine -- physically, we expect the fields to be smooth in vacuum. Finally, the result of taking the curl is a familiar equation (the wave equation) to which we already know the solutions. So we can immediately interpret the resulting equation in terms of wave solutions.

The actual step of taking the curl and simplifying is just "turning the crank" on vector calculus machinery. It's the mathematical glue needed to connect the starting point to a more useful form of the equations. There is insight in realizing that taking the curl will get you to a useful equation. That insight comes with experience, and doing lots of problems.